# Oracle Case WHERE Clause

Tags: oracle, case, where-clause, clause

I am needing to have a CASE statement in my UPDATE statement WHERE clause.  But, it is giving me a compile error:

```
   UPDATE......
   .
   .
   WHERE CASE
           WHEN p_client_id = 0 THEN user_id = p_user_id
           ELSE client_id = p_client_id
         END;

680/50   PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword
```

Am I missing something, or is this not the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you re-write it like this:

```
   UPDATE......
   .
   .
   WHERE (    p_client_id  = 0 and user_id   = p_user_id
           OR p_client_id != 0 and client_id = p_client_id )
         ;
```

My assumption (based on the original question) is that `p_client_id` is always populated. If that's not the case then you will need to amend this code to handle nulls.

Comment: You don't need the `END`. Also, if `p_client_id` is `NULL` then no rows will be matched (but that might be the expected behaviour).

Comment: @MT0 - The END was a typo, thanks for that. I acknowledge that it doesn't handle NULL for `p_client_id`, I've revised my answer to make that point

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `DECODE()` function to match conditionally such as

```
WHERE DECODE(p_client_id,0,user_id,client_id)=DECODE(p_client_id,0,p_user_id,p_client_id)
```